# What is the purpose of "DoesServiceRequest" decoration attribute in C# Azure libraries?

Tags: c#, azure-storage

[MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj733054.aspx) : `DoesServiceRequest` specifies that the method will make one or more requests to the storage service.

However it doesn't say **why** it's needed. I can decorate my own mock class with it but would like to know a bit more than blindly slapping it on my methods. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a decorator on the Storage client library API calls to let you know if that particular API call makes a request out to the storage service, or if that API call is run locally.

For example, CloudBlockBlob.FetchAttributes is decorated with DoesServiceRequest because it makes an HTTP call to Storage.  But CloudBlockBlob.GetSharedAccessSignature does not have that decorator because the function executes locally in-proc without calling out to the storage service.